# Obtaining IP Address of Callback Channel in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service on a duplex channel, with a callback contract. The service keeps track of the clients by storing the result of `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<T>()` in a list when a client calls a `SubscribeMe()` method on the service. The service will periodically ping these callback channels to keep track of their validity, and expire those that are closed or timing out.

The question I have is this: How do I get information about the remote host when the remote host is not actively making a request to my service, such as when I'm calling `MyCallbackContract.Ping()`?

I tried casting the callback channel object to `IContextChannel`, and accessing the  `IContextChannel::RemoteAddress` property, but this property contains some kind of namespace URI that has nothing to do with the actual remote host on the callback channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested (would take a while to get all the config set up!), but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty =
                messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name]
                as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

var address = endpointProperty.Address;
```

Comment: So, in my situation, there should not be an OperationContext.Current when I try to ping the list of clients. It is called periodically, and there is no service operation being invoked. If the solution is to store the remote endpoint information at the time of subscription, that may be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, in that case, use the code above  (modified to use the IncomingMessageProperties collection instead of outgoing) when the client connects and you should be ok.  Sorry it wasn't a bit more helpful, WCF isn't really my speciality :)

Comment: It's a valid solution. I just want to know if I should be tracking this or if I can rely on WCF to do so. It seems like the kind of thing the callback channel should be able to tell me.

Comment: Yeah, you'd think it probably can eh? :)  Maybe try putting a breakpoint at the point where you thing you should be able to get to it and try inspecting the object model for something useful?