# How to get server endpoint address from client callback method (wcf duplex contract)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a duplex WCF contract and I want to get server endpoint address from client callback method (I'm using single client and many servers, so I want to know which server responds to me). Is there a way to get it from the OperationContext?

```
public class CallbackService : IServiceCallback
    {
        public void OnSuccess()
        {
            string endpoint = OperationContext.Current.?
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Process on {0} successfully finished!", endpoint));
        }
    }
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262025/obtaining-ip-address-of-callback-channel-in-wcf) and tried the solution, but it responds with something unmeaningful to me: "fe80::1845:e7eb:abbb:77aa%13".

And here is what I want to get:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:5678/WinFormsHoster/wsDual">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct address, you are using IPv6.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I want to get the address as I wrote it in client's config file.

Comment: If you want that, you should consider adding some information to your message headers. I don't think you can get that kind information from the OperationContext.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to implement this, but is this solution any better than just adding "string host" argument to my callback methods? I believe this is more maitainable option, than adding it to headers.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to maintain your code. I am automatically adding a similar header in my code. I don't like the "adding as argument" because this is not part of my program logic and I don't want to add it to every method. And in some scenarios this will not work (for example: When using a stream as a argument you can't add additional arguments)